# How to have loop do one thing first time and something else other times

Tags: loops, stata

Say I have this data:

```
clear
set more off
input ///
float (b a_first a_second a_third control)
4 3 2 5 7
6 3 4 2 4
7 6 5 2 5
1 4 2 3 6
7 6 1 4 1
8 8 7 4 4
end
```

I want to create a table using outreg2:

```
foreach i in first second third {
    reg b a_`i'
    outreg2 using filename, replace
    reg b a_`i' control
    outreg2 using filename, append
}
```

(Note that `filename' is your file name of choice.) This doesn't quite do what I want. For every iteration, it creates a table with just two columns. The next time through, it replaces what was originally there with the two new regressions.

What I need it to do is only replace the very first time through and after that switch to append:

```
reg b a_first
outreg2 using filename, replace
reg b a_first control
outreg2 using filename, append
reg b a_second
outreg2 using filename, append
reg b a_second control
outreg2 using filename, append
reg b a_third
outreg2 using filename, append
reg b a_third control
outreg2 using filename, append
```

The best I can come up with is to create a local that takes value `replace` if `i==first` and use this local in the first `outreg2` statement. Is there a more straightforward way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider storing the regression estimates, then use `outreg2` outside the loop, concisely with a wildcard `[*]`. See [Example 3 of the `outreg2` doc](http://repec.org/bocode/o/outreg2):

```
foreach i in first second third {
    reg b a_`i'
    est store `i'
    reg b a_`i' control
    est store `i'control
}

outreg2 [*] using filename, replace
```

Comment: Note that `outreg` and `outreg2` are quite separate commands. Edited to be consistent.

Comment: Thanks, Nick. I did cite an outreg2 web document, but mistyped.

Comment: Quite; you are not confused, but the two programs with similar names are a frequent source of confusion among beginners.

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, note a classical alternative, which is to take the first iteration outside the loop:

```
reg b a_first
outreg2 using filename, replace
reg b a_first control
outreg2 using filename, append


foreach v in second third { 
    reg b a_`v' 
    outreg2 using filename, append
    reg b a_`v' control
    outreg2 using filename, append
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty much what you thought of, but not too ugly, since it makes use of only needing to be run the first time to avoid needing an if. I wouldn't call this an answer, but I haven't figure out how to post clean code in a comment.

```
local rep replace
foreach i in first second third {
    reg b a_`i'
    outreg2 using filename, `rep'
    local rep append
    reg b a_`i' control
    outreg2 using filename, append
}
```